# cytoscape.js add node in layout breadthfirst

Tags: javascript, cytoscape.js

I start cy (layout=breathfirst) with a group of nodes and egdes. cy calculate the tree-structure very well. But if I add a node later, cy placed the node on position 0,0. How I can inform cy to recalculate the tree structure?

Answer (score 0):

Run the breadthfirst layout again: http://js.cytoscape.org/#cy.layout